# Trouble getting Google Books API data via PHP

Tags: json, curl, google-books

The current code takes form input and does THIS to it:

```
$apikey = 'myapikey';
$q = urlencode($bookSearchTerm);
$endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' . $q . '&key=' . $apikey;
$session = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
$search_results = json_decode($data);
if ($search_results === NULL) die('Error parsing json');
```

Just for kicks, I also did

```
echo $endpoint;
```

which shows

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=lord+of+the+rings&key=myapikey
```

When I enter that URL into a browser, I get a screen full o' data, telling me that, among other things, there are 814 items.

Yet when I run the code on a page, I get

```
Error parsing json
```

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your `$data` variable isn't null to begin with?

Comment: I figured it would be set by the `$data = curl_exec($session);` line, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the response to the comment, it could be set, maybe not. It may also be the case that what is returned isn't parse-able by the parser because it isn't in the right data format. Check what `$data` gives back as a result. If it's correct then by the json_decode doc on the PHP site it may be that it's simply too big for the parser to parse (reaches recursion limit) though I doubt that.

It it is possible that the what is return just overflows the PHP allocated memory limit. PHP parses JSON into associative or numbered arrays, which can get expensive. So if what you get back is just too big, it'll fail to finish parsing and just return null.

Comment: I tried adding `echo $data;` to the end of the above, and get nothing.

Comment: Well if you get nothing then that is likely your problem. Can't very well parse nothing can you! Check the errors on the curl connection: `$curl_error($endpoint);`

Comment: Here's what $curl_error returns...  `SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Comment: Figured it out.
Added the following lines:  `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`
And everything now works.

Comment: A yeah I totally missed that! Yeah you have to configure it a bit more for SSL connections. Sorry :/